# Побитовые операции (сдвиг)

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

У меня есть число, которое в 16-ричном виде равно `B3C5B3`, как мне из него получить 16-ричное `C5B3` при помощи побитовых операций? На сколько сдвиг и в какую сторону?
Мне нужен сдвиг. Потому что полностью задача звучит так: "Программа должна поменять местами восьмерки бит, так чтобы первая восьмерка стала равной второй, а вторая первой. Например `B3C5_16` должно превратиться в `C5B3_16`". И я написал такой код на `С++`:

```
int swap(int x){
    int a = x << 8, b = x >> 8;
    int res = (a | b); 
    return res;
}
```

При этом получается почти верный результат: `B3C5_16` дает ответ `B3C5B3_16`. Вот поэтому операция "И" вроде как не подходит.

Comment: Вы почти верно сделали, нужно только наложить маску int a = (x << 8) & 0xFFFF

Comment: @MBo Спасибо вам!

Comment: Используйте беззнаковый тип данных, иначе сдвиг вправо может  дать не то, что вы ожидали

Comment: MBo, да, все работает, спасибо

Comment: Что-то у вас странное условие — из `B3C5B3` получить `C5B3`. Для этого сдвиг не нужен, просто обнулить старшие биты. Пересмотрите условие вопроса, pls...

Answer (score 3):

Со сдвигом проще всего разобраться в калькуляторе "Программист".
Берем например число 0xFF в шестнадцатеричной, это 0b1111 1111 в двоичной, четыре единицы это 0xF, полбайта.

```
Сместим это все на 1: 0b1111 1111>>1 == 0b0111 1111 == 0x7F
Сместим это все на 4: 0b1111 1111>>4 == 0b0000 1111 == 0x0F
0xB3C5B3 >> 4 == 0x0B3C5B
0xB3C5B3 >> 8 == 0x00B3C5
0xB3C5B3 >> 12 == 0x000B3C
```

В вашем случае это можно решить побитовой операцией "И" вот так
`0xB3C5B3 & 0x00FFFF == 0xC5B3`
Не забывайте про выравнивание чисел в памяти (uint32_t)0x00B3C5B3

Comment: Спасибо большое, но мне нужен сдвиг. Потому что полностью задача звучит так: "Программа должна поменять местами восьмерки бит, так чтобы первая восьмерка стала равной второй, а вторая первой. Например B3C5_16 должно превратиться в C5B3_16". И я написал такой код на С++:
```int swap(int x){
 int a = x << 8, b = x >> 8;
 int res = (a | b); 
 return res;
}```
При этом возникает почти получается результат: B3C5_16 дает ответ B3C5B3_16. Вот поэтому операция "И" вроде как не подходит.